# How to change default component in field editor windows

Tags: delphi, components, textedit

I'm using delphi with install devexpress components. Devexpress change my default text edit (Old : TDBEdit) when I drag a field into my form to e.g. cxDBTextEdit or cxDBDateEdit.

How can I change it to the default?

Comment: [Drag and Drop field](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q400971)